# How to draw in code this path

Tags: java, android, eclipse

First happy new year to all here!

I have a question about drawing background in code. I have a code for simple Android game and all assests is in png format, expect background. I`m not a programmer (but newbie in this and I learn with live examples).

I think this code draw background clouds on the screen:

```
//draw cloud layer 1
    background_shader.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));
    int radius = DrawBackgroundCloud(canvas, (ScreenHeight() / 2), 7);
    canvas.drawRect(0, (float) ((ScreenHeight() / 2.2) + radius * 1.5), ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), background_shader);

    //draw cloud layer 2
    background_shader.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_darkest));
    radius = DrawBackgroundCloud(canvas, (int) (ScreenHeight() / 1.5), 4);
    canvas.drawRect(0, (float) ((ScreenHeight() / 1.7) + radius * 1.5), ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), background_shader);
```

This draw some random circles as clouds but I want to change this to draw something like hills or mountains. Here is a picture of current background and what I`m looking for.

http://prntscr.com/5nqa25

Can anyone help me with this? I will be really thankfuly

Comment: I think you need to paste also the DrawBackgroundCloud method code.

Comment: Hey blipinsk! Thanks for response. I already solve this, but have another problem. How can I draw gradient using on canvas.drawColor element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to the further question in the comment:

you cant really do that with `canvas.drawColor`, but you can use a proper `Paint` object and use `canvas.drawPaint` (or other canvas method that uses `Paint` object - if you want to for example draw shape with gradient).

The key part of creating your gradient `Paint` object is calling its `setShader(...)` method. For example like so:

```
mGradientPaint = new Paint();
mGradientPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
mGradientPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

Comment: This is now my code for drawing background. How can I use your code with my current? 

public void renderBackground(Canvas canvas) {
  //draw background
  canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));

Thanks so much!

Comment: just as I wrote you in my answer: create an appropriate `Paint` object, and INSTEAD of your code, use `canvas.drawPaint(<YOUR_PAINT_OBJECT>);`

Comment: blipinsk: thanks! I`m a newbie to this, so I will research on google how can I create appropriate Paint object and apply your code on it. Thanks!

Comment: The "appropriate" part mostly refers to the setShader method call.

Comment: Do it inside the class that represents your view (so the one that has those lines of yours that use `canvas`). Create a field inside the class (not an argument inside the method, but a FIELD - read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html if you're not familiar with fields) that will keep the `Paint` object. So for example like this `Paint mGradientPaint;`. Then in constructor of the view, initiate this `Paint` object with lines just like in my answer.

Comment: blipinks: like a boss! Now it`s working. Thank you so much :)